# How to get how many online players are there online in bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin that sends data to server about online players.
How to get how many online players are there and put it into a variable/string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look at the existing plugin that has this capability. Check it at http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/player-count-message/

you may be able to achieve your need by using `%online%` tag

If you want to code, below may help:

```
getServer().getOnlinePlayers();
```

OR

```
Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().length
```

Answer (score 4):

As of CraftBukkit e6cd8c0, the return type for Server#getOnlinePlayers() changed from Player[] to a List. Therefore, to reflect those changes, use

```
Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers().size()
```

instead.